# How to send voice sms to another contact number using button click Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

How to send voice SMS to another contact number using button onclick and I also want to auto schedule here, like once user will click on button then voice call need to send after every 1 minute repeatedly.

please help me to give some guidance and tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at below link

http://code.google.com/p/google-voice-java/w/list

[EDIT 1]

For a repeating task:

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(task, after, interval);
```

task being the method to be executed

after the time to initial execution

(interval the time for repeating the execution)

[EDIT 2]

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.util.*;

public class TimerDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // creating timer task, timer
      TimerTask tasknew = new TimerScheduleFixedRate();
      Timer timer = new Timer();

      // scheduling the task at fixed rate
      timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tasknew,new Date(),1000);      
   }
   // this method performs the task
   public void run() {
      System.out.println("working at fixed rate");      
   }    
}
```

Let us compile and run the above program, this will produce the following result.

working at fixed rate

working at fixed rate

working at fixed rate

working at fixed rate and so on ...

Comment: how to send voice message to pre defined number after every 1 minute

Comment: thanks for support can  i have a sample how to get device location using button click

Comment: i have found a tutorial by using that i am getting longitude and latitude of current location but now i want to get each and every detail of that location, like: country, city, state, street, house number, zip code and more.......

Comment: It is not related with this question. Ask it in new question, i will  reply.